# How to work with TF Lite library in a c++ project

Tags: c++, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I've been struggling in the last 1-2 days with how to build TensorFlow Lite so I can use it as headers or library in my own C\C++ project.

For example, I have a C++ project with main.cpp with the following code:

```
#include "tensorflow/lite/model.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/interpreter.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/kernels/register.h"

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<tflite::FlatBufferModel> model;
    model = tflite::FlatBufferModel::BuildFromBuffer(h5_converted_tflite, h5_converted_tflite_len);

    tflite::ops::builtin::BuiltinOpResolver resolver;
    std::unique_ptr<tflite::Interpreter> interpreter;
    tflite::InterpreterBuilder(*model, resolver)(&interpreter);

    // Resize input tensors, if desired.
    interpreter->AllocateTensors();

    float* input = interpreter->typed_input_tensor<float>(0);
    // Fill `input`.

    interpreter->Invoke();

    float* output = interpreter->typed_output_tensor<float>(0);
}
```

What should I download\build, and from where, so I can successfully compile this code? Currently it says, obviously, that the h files cannot be found, and when I clone the TF repository and add it to the include folders, it doesn't find "flatbuffers.h" file, and when I add it manually, it gives me many linkage errors.
Any help will be appreciated here...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Depending on your architecture and os you are targeting, you will find all the necessary files to build tf lite here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/lite/tools/make. First you have to run the script to install the dependencies and then you should be able to run the makefile.

Comment: @pierrom Thanks a lot. My OS is a 64-bit windows. Should I run download_dependencies.sh and then build_aarch64_lib.sh ? What would be the output of these scripts?

Comment: No aarch64 won't work for you. This is for ARM processor which are used in android smartphones. On Github there is a pull request that tries to implement the build config for tf lite on windows but it hasn't been merged yet.

Comment: @pierrom Can I please have a link to that PR to view its changes\additions?

Comment: Sure https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/16490. And here is also an issue discussing the problem https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/14607

Comment: @pierrom if this PR is merged, will we have a script that outputs an so or lib file so one can use in a stand-alone c\c++ project?

Comment: The TFLite team is actively working to improve C++ interop for clients not using Bazel. https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/android#use_tflite_c_api has some additional on C++ interop for Android, and we're also looking at CMake support in the next few months.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code, which has been tested with `TensorFlow` lite 1.14.0:

```
std::string str = "model.tflite";
ifstream file(str, std::ifstream::binary);
file.seekg(0, file.end);
int length = file.tellg();
file.seekg(0, file.beg);
char * model_data = new char [length];
file.read (model_data, length);
file.close();
std::unique_ptr<tflite::Interpreter> interpreter;
std::unique_ptr<tflite::FlatBufferModel> model;
tflite::ops::builtin::BuiltinOpResolver resolver;
model = tflite::FlatBufferModel::BuildFromBuffer(model_data, length);
tflite::InterpreterBuilder(*model, resolver)(&interpreter);
interpreter->AllocateTensors();
```

Comment: It looks like something vital is missing: what is the `resolver`?

Comment: Sorry `tflite::ops::builtin::BuiltinOpResolver resolver;`

Answer (score 1):

Recently, TFLite supports CMake and it seems that it resolves your dependency issue.

https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/build_cmake#create_a_cmake_project_which_uses_tensorflow_lite